jenkins installation error in ubuntu 22.04
am using ubuntu and i am getting error while installing jenkins
Cannot initiate the connection to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn:443 (2402:f000:1:400::2). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn:443 (101.6.15.130), connection timed out E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/jenkins/debian-stable/jenkins_2.361.2_all.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn:443 (2402:f000:1:400::2). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) How to solve this?
i am  installating jenkins in my local machine ubuntu 22.04

I understand that you are trying to install Jenkins in your Ubuntu 22.04 but getting above error.
If you see the error you are trying to install Jenkins version -- jenkins_2.361.2_all.deb but this version is not available in the repository. Visit the university link here and check which all versions are supported.
I have added a screenshot for your reference and you can see that your Jenkins version is not available.

